# Fullcalendar re-renders all events on updateEvent and when an event is dragged and dropped

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a reason (or have I set something up wrong)? I think this may be causing quite bad performance in IE8.

http://jsfiddle.net/t6rx6rmr/

```
 var events = [{title: "fasdfdas", start: new Date()},{title: "event 2", start: new Date()}]

$(".calendar").fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    eventRender: function(event, element){
        console.log("rendering" +event.title);
    }
});
$(".calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", events[0]);
$(".calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", events[1]);
console.log("loaded");
$(".calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", events[0]);
```

Thanks,
B

Comment: have you tried version 2.3? why are you using a very old v1?

Comment: Hi I'm actually using the fullcalendar with year view fork (https://github.com/tpruvot/yearcalendar) which is based on v.1.6.4, but the same behaviour happens in v2.3.

Comment: Here is a fiddle using v2.3 http://jsfiddle.net/a5xbgv5L/1/